# Ag-Grid React - interact redux with Ag-grid server side row model

Tags: reactjs, redux, ag-grid-react

I have a case where I need to manipulate the data with some variable stored in a redux state.

I am using Ag-Grid React, server-side row model the problem when this state are updated ag grid is not aware of this update

I have tried everything

1- `useCallback` for `onGridReady` and give my redux state as dependency

```
const onGridReady = useCallback(
    (params: GridReadyEvent) => {
      // pass reference to parent
      setGridRef?.call(null, gridRef);
      // register datasource with the grid
      params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
    },
    [toolImages]
  );
```

2- pass the redux state as param inside datasource callback

```
const datasource: IServerSideDatasource = {
    getRows: (params: IServerSideGetRowsParams) => {
      loadData(params.request, params.api.paginationGetPageSize(), toolImages)
        .then((response) => {
          params.success({
            rowData: response.rowData,
            rowCount: response.rowCount,
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          params.fail();
        });
    },
  };
```

3- inside my loadData method make it

```
 const loadData = useCallback(
        (params: IServerSideGetRowsRequest, localPageSize: number, images: any) => {
          console.log('loadData_changed', images);
          return handleLoadData(params, localPageSize, images);
        },
    
        [toolImages]
      );
```

but all these solutions are not working

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me is

```
gridRef.current.context = { ...gridRef.current.context, 'data': data};
```

in useEffect method, then retrieve it by `serverSideParams.api.context`